# An artinian ring is Noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, artinian

I am trying to understand the proof for Artinian $\implies$ Noetherian given in chapter 16 of "Abstract Algebra (3rd edition)" by Dummit and Foote.

The proof given in the textbook goes as follows.

> It suffices by (4) to prove that an Artinian local ring is Noetherian, so
> assume $R$ is Artinian with unique maximal ideal $M$. In this case we have $M = Jac R$,
> so $M^m= (JacR)^m$ for some m. Then $R\simeq R/M^m$ and it is an exercise to see that $R/M^m$ is Noetherian (cf. Exercise 8)

(4) Here is the previous proposition which states that every artinian is isomorphic to a finite direct product of local artinian rings. The proof for this gives the isomorphism
$$
    A\simeq A/M_1^m\times A/M_2^m\times ... \times A/M_n^m
$$
where $M_1,..,M_n$ are the maximal ideals of $A$ and each $A/M_i^m$ is an artinian local ring with maximal ideal $M/M_i^m$.

And exercise (8) is: Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of the ring $A$ and suppose $M^n=0$ for some $n\geq1$. Then $A$ is Noetherian if and only it is Artinian.

I understand the proof for (4) and I have proven (8) but this proof still doesn't make to me.

We need to show that $A/M_i^n$, a local artinian ring, is noetherian. This concludes our proof because direct product of noetherian rings is noetherian. But how is $A/M_i^n$ proven to be noetherian?

Comment: The maximal ideal $M_i/M_i^n$ of $A/M_i^n$ satisfies $(M_i/M_i^n)^n=M_i^n/M_i^n=0$. So you can apply exercise (8) to $A/M_i^n$

Comment: Ah! So close yet so far. Still don't understand though, what's all that stuff about the jacobson radical being the unique maximal ideal of local artinian ring $R$?

Comment: Maybe there was some theorem that says that in an Artinian ring the Jacobson radical is nilpotent, i.e. $J(R)^m=0$ for some $m$. Now if we are in the local case we have $J(R)=M$ hence $M^m=0$ for some $m$ and therefore $R\simeq R/M^m$